# looping search console days in API to get full days data

Tags: python, rest, google-search-console

I'm trying to take the example pseudo code on https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/how-tos/all-your-data (Overview heading)

And apply it to my script, since there's a limit of 25,000 rows per call. The solution would be for each day, starting from the first loop iteration, I will get the max amount of rows (25,000), then next iteration would be the starting row of the last insert row (i.e. 25,000). For example:

- 0 start row: 25,000 rows
- 25,000 start row: 25,000 rows inserted,
- 50,000 start row: 25,000, rows inserted
- 75,000 start row: 25,000, rows inserted
- ..... and so on

So far, I'm struggling to achieve this and not sure where to put this while loop.

I've tried placing it below - but the filters are missed in the loop (it will only get the mobile data and even then looks like it misses some other filters):

```
        startRowindexIterator = 0
        while True:

            for filter_set in generate_filters(page=pages, device=args.devices, country=args.countries):
                    print day
                    request = {
                        'startDate' : day,
                        'endDate' : day,
                        'dimensions' : ["page","query"],
                        'startRow' : startRowindexIterator * args.max_rows_per_day,
                        'rowLimit' : args.max_rows_per_day,
                        'dimensionFilterGroups' : [
                            {
                                "groupType" : "and",
                                "filters" : filter_set
                            }
                        ]
                    }

                    response = execute_request(service, args.property_uri, request)
                    print 'startRowIterator: '+ str(startRowindexIterator)
                    print 'maxRows: '+ str(args.max_rows_per_day)

                    if response is None:
                        logging.error("Request failed %s", json.dumps(request, indent=2))
                        continue

                    if 'rows' in response:
                        startRowindexIterator = startRowindexIterator + 1

                        print 'rows: '+ str(len(response['rows']))

                        if pages:
                            filters = [pages[0], 'worldwide', 'all_devices', args.url_type]
                        else:
                            filters = ['gsc_property', 'worldwide', 'all_devices', args.url_type]

                        filter_mapping = {'page': 0, 'country': 1, 'device': 2}
                        for _filter in filter_set:
                            filters[filter_mapping[_filter['dimension']]] = _filter['expression']
```

The code is based off https://github.com/stephan765/Google-Search-Console-bulk-query/blob/master/search_console_query.py

I've modified it to use a service account instead and a few tweaks to work with my python version and environment, the below is the rest of the relevant code (no while loop added) - which obviously means we're limited to 25,000 rows for each device:

```
     for day in date_range(start_date, end_date):
        output_file = os.path.join(
            args.output_location,
            "{}_{}.csv".format(args.url_type, day.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
        )
        day = day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        output_rows = []

        for filter_set in generate_filters(page=pages, device=args.devices, country=args.countries):
                request = {
                    'startDate' : day,
                    'endDate' : day,
                    'dimensions' : ["page","query"],
                    'rowLimit' : args.max_rows_per_day,
                    'dimensionFilterGroups' : [
                        {
                            "groupType" : "and",
                            "filters" : filter_set
                        }
                    ]
                }

                response = execute_request(service, args.property_uri, request)

                if 'rows' in response:

                    if pages:
                        filters = [pages[0], 'worldwide', 'all_devices', args.url_type]
                    else:
                        filters = ['gsc_property', 'worldwide', 'all_devices', args.url_type]

                    filter_mapping = {'page': 0, 'country': 1, 'device': 2}
                    for _filter in filter_set:
                        filters[filter_mapping[_filter['dimension']]] = _filter['expression']

                print len(response['rows'])
```

I expect the ability to loop until all records have been retrieved for each day and device. End result when I run a command like:

`./script.py https://example.com/ 2019-01-01 2019-01-01 --max-rows-per-day=25000`

I will be able to get all data for all devices for the given day.

Comment: can you please trim down your code to only the problematic piece so that the example is as minimal as possible. as it currently is this is entirely too much code.

Comment: @aws_apprentice Ok, i've gone ahead and done that. Thanks

Comment: this is still entirely too much code I am voting to close this question until that is fixed

Comment: @aws_apprentice I've removed all the functions as well, I presume you can view the rest on the github link

Comment: sorry this is too much code still, I suggest looking at this criteria to understand what a good question entails --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @aws_apprentice - done, hopefully this is ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188608/discussion-between-meisam-ebrahimi-and-aws-apprentice).